# Stack Overflow CSS only contains platform-specific border-radius definitions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, design, opera

I've recently switched from Firefox to Opera, and I've noticed that certain elements, for example, `.bounty-award`, do not have rounded corners anymore.  Delving into the CSS reveals that only `-webkit-border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius` are defined, but `border-radius` is not.

[`border-radius`, as the official CSS3 property](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/), should be defined as well, seeing as it is supported in recent versions of Chrome and Opera, in addition to [being the **only** `border-radius` variant supported in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635851/support-for-border-radius-in-ie).

Adding a proper `border-radius: 3px` rule via Dragonfly (like Firebug for Opera) solves this problem.

Comment: This is more of a bug than a feature request, IMO.

Comment: @Brant - I wasn't sure what to file it as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of Jin's new designs go for the [trifecta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trifecta) and bet on all 3.

`border-radius` as the official property is a recent development which postdates the Stack Overflow stylesheet.

I went ahead and added it in to the SO and Meta stylesheets. Should be deployed today.